# back to main view from popover view

Tags: iphone, ipad

I want to back to main view from popover view 
here i explain you

```
-(void)tapAction1:(UITapGestureRecognizer*) sender
{

Clicked = sender.view.tag-500;
DemoViewController *sign = [[DemoViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DemoViewController" bundle:nil];


[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.view cache:YES];

UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
UIView* popoverView = [[UIView alloc]
                       initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,  100,  sign.view.frame.size.height)];
popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
popoverContent.view = popoverView;
    [popoverView addSubview: sign.view];

//resize the popover view shown
//in the current view to the view's size
popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake( sign.view.frame.size.width, sign.view.frame.size.height);

//create a popover controller
UIPopoverController* popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                                initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
CGRect popoverRect = [self.view convertRect:[sender.view frame]
                                   fromView:[sender.view superview]];

popoverRect.size.width = MIN(popoverRect.size.width, 500);
popoverRect.origin.x  = popoverRect.origin.x;
//popoverRect.size.height  = ; 
//present the popover view non-modal with a
//refrence to the toolbar button which was pressed
[popover presentPopoverFromRect:popoverRect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

//release the popover content
[popoverView release];
[popoverContent release]; 
//[[self view] addSubview:sign.view];

[UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Now in demoviewcontroller is one xib. In which i want to put one button named close and i want to close this popover.

Comment: but UIPopoverController gets dismissed whenever clicked other than UIPopoverController's view means on parent view

Comment: yes you are right but i don't want this, i want to close this popover with close button which is shown in popver view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make the `UIPopoverController* popover` an property in `DemoViewController`.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPopoverController* popover;
```

Then you can pass the popover, allocated in the code you have posted, to this class:

```
sign.popover = popover;
```

Add this selector to  `DemoViewController`

```
- (IBAction) didClickDismissPopoverButton:(id)sender
{
    [self.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

and then just connect this IBAction with UIButton Touch Up Inside event in Interface Builder.

Comment: in which file i have to create this method????  my main file or other xib(demoveiwcontroller) which is open.

Comment: I have just extended my answer, now it should be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Add button in DemoViewController like this:

```
UIButton *btnClose = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[btnClose addFrame:CGRectMake(20,20,80,30)];
[btnClose setTitle:@"Close" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnClose addTarget:self action:@selector(dissmissPopOver:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[sign addSubView:btnClose];
```

Now selector is:

```
- (void)dissmissPopOver:(id)sender
{
  [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```